# Why is this SVG file blank when generated by QSvgGenerator from a QGLWidget?

Tags: qt, svg, qglwidget

I am displaying a data plot with [QwtPlot3D](http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/), using Qt5. The plots are rendered on a several-times sub-classed QGLWidget. The plots in question look similar to this:

[image: Example Plot]

I am using the following code to write the files, as instructed by other sources, by rendering the QGLWidget into the QPainter, which takes in a QSvgGenerator when I call `QPainter::begin`. A similar process works for writing raster images, but the SVG files seem to be empty (but they do write).

Note that the currentPlot variable is of the Plot class, which inherits SurfacePlot, which inherits Plot3D, which inherits QGLWidget.

```
void PlotWindow::writeCurrentPlotToSVG(const QString& directory,
                                       const QString& filename)
{  
    QSvgGenerator generator;
    QString ext = ".svg";
    QString filepath = buildPath(directory, filename, ext);
    generator.setFileName(filepath);
    generator.setSize(currentPlot->size());
    generator.setViewBox(currentPlot->rect());
    generator.setTitle(currentPlot->title());
    generator.setDescription("description");

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(&generator);
    currentPlot->render(&painter);
    painter.end();
}
```

The generated file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="225.778mm" height="169.333mm"
 viewBox="0 0 640 480"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny">
<title>Plot_0</title>
<desc>description</desc>
<defs>
</defs>
<g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="bevel" >

</g>
</svg>
```

Viewing the file in Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox displays nothing. I have checked that the display rectangle and the size values passed to the generator are correct. At this point, I am not sure what else to do.

Thank you for the help, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SVG outputs vector graphics, OpenGL outputs bitmap data to the framebuffer, so it is not directly possible to get scalable vector graphics from QGLWidget. I would expect QSvgGenerator to grab OpenGL content too (at least as a bitmap), but it does not seem to do that...
I've had a similar problem rendering an offscreen QGLWidget. My workaround was first render() the whole widget (you'll get no OpenGL content), then use a seperate FBO to render the QGLWidget to that and then draw the image I get from that FBO on top of the first render.
Something along those lines:

```
//find your QGL-sub-widget
qglWidget = ...
//render parent widget into the svg
QPainter painter(&svgGenerator);
widget->render(&painter);
//create/resize FBO. make the OpenGL context current, so the FBO is created in the correct context
qglChild->makeCurrent();
QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat fboFormat;
fboFormat.setSamples(4);
fboFormat.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
fbo = new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(newWindowRect.size(), fboFormat);
//get the position and size of the QGLWidget within the widget
QRect newWindowRect = GetChildRectInParent(widget, qglChild);
//the position is reliably off by one pixel in x and y, so adjust it
newWindowRect.adjust(-1, -1, -1, -1);
//make the OpenGL context current, so the FBO is created in the correct context
qglChild->makeCurrent();
//bind FBO for rendering to it
fbo->bind();
//Painting to an FBO using OpenGL content in Qt is only possible with a QOpenGLPaintDevice
QOpenGLPaintDevice fboPaintDev(newWindowRect.size());
QPainter fboPainter(&fboPaintDev);
fboPainter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
//now render the QGraphicsView
qglChild->render(&fboPainter);
fboPainter.end();
fbo->release();
//grab image from FBO and paint it at the correct position in the pixmap we grabbed from the parent widget
QPixmap openGLPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(fbo->toImage());
painter.drawPixmap(newWindowRect, openGLPixmap);
painter.end();
delete fbo;
```